# What is the status of this patent?

Tags: international, pct, legal-status, wo2013091018a1

How can I figure out if [PCT/AU2012/001589](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=US128465182) is granted or not?

There is a prior art case with [US 2,223,561 A](https://www.google.com/patents/US2223561) patented in 1939, but I don't know how to track that case.

Comment: No need to "track" US 2,223,561, it's been expired for something like 60 years.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically an Australian App -
PCT Reference: Application Number:PCT/AU2012/001589

The equivalent US App is US 2014-0370781 A1
The Public PAIR for the US App has the status as "Docketed New Case - Ready for Examination"

To track the application go to http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair and type in the "Publication Number"

Comment: thank you - yes it is a PCT Application. BTW, what is a PCT Patent? Never heard of it. The countries' /regional Patent Office prosecute the PCT Application into a patent for their jurisdiction - where does PCT Patent happen?

Comment: The original application was filed in Australia, but it is a PCT application.

Comment: I should have said "application", not "patent". The process is described [here](http://www.wipo.int/pct/en/faqs/faqs.html), specifically the [overview figure](http://www.wipo.int/export/sites/www/pct/images/overview.gif).

Answer (score 0):

This PCT patent is currently in the National Phase, which means there are publications in multiple countries, each with its own status. You can find these on the "National Status" tab of the page you linked to:

```
Office                   Entry Date  National Number  National Status
Australia                03.07.2014  2012357650       Published: 24.07.2014
Canada                   02.06.2014  2857701          
European Patent Office   18.06.2014  2012859200       
United States of America 03.06.2014  14362446         Published: 18.12.2014
```

Each country has its own system for managing the publications. The USPTO provides US legal status via [Public Pair](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair). The [Canadian](http://brevets-patents.ic.gc.ca/opic-cipo/cpd/eng/patent/2857701/summary.html) and [Australian](http://pericles.ipaustralia.gov.au/ols/auspat/applicationDetails.do?applicationNo=2012357650) patent systems have the status built into the web pages linked to from PatentScope and are easier to find. The [EPO system](https://register.epo.org/application?number=EP12859200) is a little more complex, but the information is available on the Legal Status and Event History pages.

Comment: thanks again Vallismortis. What about the rest of the world? South America for example? It depends on the US system?

Comment: @CristobalCerda The last time I checked, there were over 80 patent authorities in different countries, and they have no dependency on the US system. Many of them are member states to the [Patent Cooperation Treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patent_Cooperation_Treaty) (PCT) but some are not. I can't account for them all, but the WIPO patent National Status is the definitive place to look for PCT patents.

Comment: The PCT now has [148 member states](http://www.wipo.int/pct/en/pct_contracting_states.html).

Comment: Not to be too picky, but I believe this is an application, not a patent.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the link
https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=US128465182

You will see the following (and more):
Application Number: 14362446    Application Date:   21.12.2012
Publication Number: 20170245476 Publication Date:   18.12.2014
**Grant Number: 09826721    Grant Date: 28.11.2017**

You are interested in the the grant date mentioned here.

Alternate method use google : https://patents.google.com/patent/US20170245476/pt-pt

On the right hand side you will see:
the granted patent number : **US9826721B2** and the 
granted patent date: 2017-11-28

You could get this information from espacenet (https://worldwide.espacenet.com/?locale=en_EP) or any other public domain database easily.

If you need to know the status of the application in a particular country you will need to use the global dossier